# Button no tiene atributo sample al usar random.sample

Tags: python, funciones, botón, atributos

Estoy usando random.sample para extraer una string de una lista. Cuando programo para que la funcion suceda al tocar un botón, si toco el botón me aparece "AttributteError: 'Button' has no attribute 'sample'"
Dejo el código del botón:

```
random = Button(ventana, text="Generar Nueva Paleta", font=("Comic Sans MS", 10), command= lambda:color(), bg="#CCCCFF", fg="black")
```

Y de la función:

```
def color():

hexa=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9,]

c1, c2, c3, c4, c5 = random.sample(hexa, 5)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu error se debe a que cuando creas el botón, lo guardas en una variable llamada `random`. Esto hace que después, cuando llamas a `random.sample`, en realidad estés haciendo `(el botón que hiciste).sample`, y el Button de Tkinter no tiene el metodo `sample`.

La solución a tu problema sería cambiar la variable en la que guardas tu botón a otro nombre. Como por ejemplo:

```
b_random = Button(ventana, ...)
```